# OpenID Connect: Use username as subject without script mapper

Tags: keycloak

By default, Keycloak provides the user id as sub(ject) in the OIDC ID token. But instead, I need the username as subject. I already tried the mentioned solutions for older, similar questions:

1. Using a script mapper (deprecated feature, not available in my environment / version 8.0.2 anymore)
2. Using a user attribute mapper (does not work)

Is there any other known solution?

Comment: Depending on your environment the [Keycloak Client Adapters](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#what-are-client-adapters) help you get all of the user attributes easily.  It does not change the user id to username but you can get the user name.  What is your server environment?